# how can i make a new column based on multiple conditions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem with this task. I want to create a new column size based on the criteria in the first image, so how can I do this ?
I tried to use the case when but not working

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: update your question and add  your case query code..

Comment: Please show your solution attempts

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Please don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, we cannot cut and paste from an image, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
SELECT animaltype,
       CASE WHEN animaltype = 'Dog'
                THEN CASE WHEN weight <= 10 THEN 'Small'
                          WHEN weight BETWEEN 10 AND 30 THEN 'Medium'
                          ELSE 'Large'
                     END
            WHEN animaltype = 'Cat'
                THEN CASE WHEN weight <= 5 THEN 'Small'
                          WHEN weight BETWEEN 5 AND 7 THEN 'Medium'
                          ELSE 'Large'
                     END    
            WHEN animaltype = 'Bird'
                THEN CASE WHEN weight <= 0.7 THEN 'Small'
                          WHEN weight BETWEEN 0.7 AND 1.1 THEN 'Medium'
                          ELSE 'Large'
                     END        
       end AS Size
FROM animal
```